# i want to create a page in PrestaShop 1.7, but i get a path error

Tags: php, templates, smarty, prestashop-1.7

I want to create a page on PrestaShop, so I create a file in the folder controller:
**/contollers/front/MapageController.php**

Then in this file I insert this code:

```
class MapageControllerCore extends FrontController
{
    public $php_self = 'mapage';
    public $page_name = 'ma-page';
    public $ssl = true;
    /**
     * Initialize Ma Page controller.
     *
     * @see FrontController::initContent()
     */
    public function initContent()
    {
        parent::initContent();
        $this->context->smarty->assign('content_only', 0);

      $this->setTemplate('costumer/mapage');
    }
}
```

And I create a **mapage.tpl** file in the costum folder:
**/Themes/classic/templates/customer**

***When I view the map in the browser, I get this error:***

> [PrestaShopException]
>
> No template found for costumer/mapage
>   at line 68 in file classes/Smarty/TemplateFinder.php

```
63.                     return $tpl;
64.                 }
65.             }
66.         }
67. 
68.         throw new PrestaShopException('No template found for '.$template);
69.     }
70. 
71.     private function getTemplateHierarchy($template, $entity, $id)
72.     {
73.         $entity = basename($entity);
```

- TemplateFinderCore->getTemplate - [line 1340 -
  classes/controller/FrontController.php] - [4 Arguments]
- FrontControllerCore->getTemplateFile - [line 1236 -
  classes/controller/FrontController.php] - [3 Arguments]
- FrontControllerCore->setTemplate - [line 50 -
  controllers/front/SportsHiverController.php] - [1 Arguments]
- SportsHiverControllerCore->initContent - [line 201 -
  classes/controller/Controller.php]
- ControllerCore->run - [line 366 -    classes/Dispatcher.php]
- DispatcherCore->dispatch - [line 28 -    index.php]

someone can help me?
Thank's

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->setTemplate('costumer/mapage');
```

In the  above code to set template, you have to modify the code like this:

```
$this->setTemplate('module:modulename/views/templates/front/mapage.tpl');
```

**Note**: You have to create a mapage.tpl file in your module folder in views/templates/front/

Comment: Welcome... @Ahmed